# Error converting 2 varchar attributes to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database where the `CREATEDATE` and `CREATETIME` are stored in 2 separate attributes as varchars. I'm trying to combine these 2 into a single `smalldatetime` attribute.

When I run the following conversion, I receive the error:

`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

```
UPDATE UsersTemp
SET Created =   CONVERT(datetime, CAST(CONVERT(date, CreateDateIMF, 102)AS varchar(50)) 
            + ' ' +
            CASE WHEN LEN(CreateTime) = 6 THEN 
                 Left(CreateTime, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CreateTime, 2, 2)
            ELSE 
                 Left(CreateTime, 1) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CreateTime, 1, 2)
            END
            + ':' + Right(CreateTime, 2), 120)
```

*(Yes this is messy SQL, but it's only temporary to get this data in a way I can use it better)*

I have tried a number of different things when working with the whole set and I can't seem to get it to work.

When trying the above parameters in a `SELECT`, the date works fine, so the problem exists in the time field but I'm not sure how to correct it.

Example Original Data:

```
CREATEDATEIMF
 20120220
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20040415
 20050510

CREATETIME
 160401
 142304
 142304
 142304
 142304
 142304
 142304
 142304
 142304
 44427
```

I have confirmed that the time is HMMSS. (note there are no leading 0's on the short hours)

This data is a dump from an old COBOL program.

Comment: Are you sure its not just that smalldatetime doesn't support seconds? (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182418.aspx)

Comment: @chrisb no, the seconds get truncated, they don't prevent the conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (CREATEDATE VARCHAR(32), CREATETIME VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @x VALUES
('20120101','142304'),
('20120101','44427');

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 
  CREATEDATE + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('00' 
  + CREATETIME, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
FROM @x;
```

So in your case,

```
UPDATE dbo.UsersTemp SET Created = CONVERT(DATETIME, 
  CREATEDATE + ' ' + STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' 
  + CREATETIME, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'));
```

Now, since you chose to store date/time data using the *wrong* data type, there is no guarantee that all of the values you have in there will in fact convert appropriately.

Comment: +1 for giving an answer *and* a warning about appropriate data types.

Comment: This worked. I didn't realize that `smalldatetime` truncated seconds, thank you. But, I don't care about seconds in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('000000' + CAST(createtime AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) paddedCreateTime
FROM yourTable
```

should make the 44427 look like 044427  but I'm not sure if this is where your problem is

Comment: Well, try `SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '044427');` - this answer is not complete.